# How to use data from .m file into another?

Tags: matlab

In the following code, I need **1 lakh** samples in the array **mydata**. I don't know what I am getting out of **mydata**. Do I have to increase the range of **t** to get that. And how can I use the data in **mydata** into another .m file for further processing.

```
t  = [ 1 : 1 : 500]; % Time Samples
f1=10000; % Input Signal Frequency
f2=20000;
f3=30000;
f4=f2+f3;
f5=f1+f3;
f6=f4+f2;
f7=f1+f6;
f8=45000;
f9=55000;
f10=35000;
mydata=[1:100000];
Fs = 100000; % Sampling Frequency
for i=1:100000
    if(i<=10000)
        mydata = sin(2*pi*f1/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>10000)&&(i<=20000))
       mydata=sin(2*pi*f2/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>20000)&&(i<=30000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f3/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>30000)&&(i<=40000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f4/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>40000)&&(i<=50000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f5/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>50000)&&(i<=60000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f6/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>60000)&&(i<=70000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f7/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>70000)&&(i<=80000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f8/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>80000)&&(i<=90000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f9/Fs*t);
    elseif((i>90000)&&(i<=100000))
        mydata=sin(2*pi*f10/Fs*t);
    end
end
stem(mydata)
```

Comment: 1 lakh? 1000? Are you looking to produce 10000 samples? You can do zero-order-hold sampling by using the modulo operation...

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. Please rephrase and tell us exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code doesn't do very much; you know that, right?
if we don't know/understand what you want, we can't help..

and for anyone else: 1 lakh = 100 000 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)

edit: are you trying to produce an array of 100000 samples, consisting of a fixed number of points from different sine waves? aka:

```
[sin(1.0*pi*[0:10])  sin(2.0*pi*[0:10] sin(1.5*pi*[0:10] (etc) ]
```

edit2: you repeated your earlier question (which was already answered): [How can I generate a sine wave with different frequencies using matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199019/need-to-generate-a-sine-wavve-with-diffrent-frequencies-using-matlab)

Comment: yes i want to create an array mydata which has 1 lakh points from diffrent sine waves. 
my code is written to produce sine wave which changes its frequency after every 10,000 points. 
and all this is saved in mydata. So This array should contain 1 lakh points. My question is how can i know that mydata has 1 lakh points and how can i see them?

later on i need to use these points to perform fft on them. so how can i use mydata for further processing in a different script

Comment: Then you have an error in your code. It should be like mydata(i) = sin(2*pi*f1/Fs*(i-10000)); or similar. Cause at the moment you overwrite the mydata array with smaller arrays.

Comment: yeah thanks this was my problem and also i shouldnt have declared mydata before hand. Work done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt understand what you want to do with mydata, please be more specific, because your code is wrong and I cant figure what you want to create.

Whereas for the problem on having the data to be used on other script one simple way would just write mydata into disc,

by doing on your script:

```
save path_for_mydata/file_name.mat mydata
```

And on the other script:

```
load path_formydata/file_name.mat
```

One other way, would be to create a function, and pass it as a parameter.

Finally, you could just run the first script, and then the second script on command line or on one third script that would call this both scripts, the parameters from the first script will be saved on transient memory while the second script runs.